# Trying to come up with Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to parse this string: `*(!((stunned)||dead))`

Currently have

```
// ["*", "!", "stunned", "||dead"]
string.match(/[^()]+/g)
```

Trying to get 
`["*", "!", "stunned", "||", "dead"]`

Ideally in a way that would also separate it regarless of placement `"||dead"` or `"dead||"`

while support `||, &&, ==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want to either match word characters, or non-word characters which are not parentheses:

```js
const str = '*(!((stunned)||dead))';
console.log(str.match(/\w+|[^()\w]+/g));
```

Comment: Brilliant, is there a way to make it affect && || == as far as the non word characters go?

Comment: But you also have `*` and `!` which are non-word characters. Is there a specific input for which this does not produce the desired output?

Comment: Sorry rethinking the whole structure of things, quick question though - 
how would I get a side of a string, ex: " keyword : value " 

What regex would yield me the left side of the colon without including the colon.

Comment: `const [keyword] = string.split(':')` or `const keyword = string.match(/[^:]+/)[0]`

Comment: Is it possible to get just 1 value without traversing through the array?

Comment: Both of those methods in the above comment will extract that one value from the array, is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh wait, I got it ^ at the beginning or $ at the end. I am learning!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208028/discussion-between-ayn-and-certainperformance).

Comment: How would I go about capturing strings and asterisk outside of quotes only?

[link] https://jsfiddle.net/z4n0cLx6/

@CertainPerformance

Comment: Negative lookahead for non-`(` characters followed by `)`: `(?:[a-z]+|\*)(?![^(]*\))`